# Using custom view in recycler view

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I see a need in my project to move from ListView to RecyclerView. But right I am facing some issues on adapter implementation.

In my current ListView implementation I am using CustomView instead of inflating there. Here is my current getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View containerRow, ViewGroup parent) {
        return PanelViewFactory.createPanel(..)
}
```

But in the RecyclerView adapter there is no getView() method. We need to bind this custom view into respective view holder. But how can I do ths in current implementation since I m not inflating any layout in adapter. The view inflation is done in PanelViewFactory  and i got only view instance here,. So please help me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom View in a RecyclerView Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522121/use-custom-view-in-a-recyclerview-adapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would inflate in [onCreateViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) of your recycler adapter as follows:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_row_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view, this);
}
```

This is where you can create your custom view.

Comment: The question asks how to use a custom view inside a `RecyclerView`.  Directly inflating XML is not using a custom view.

Comment: There is no rule that says a custom view needs to be directly attached to the parent view only programmatically.  A well defined custom view should render in the xml editor properly.  I can create a layout file where my only view is the custom view `<com.mypackage.MyCustomView>...</com.mypackage.MyCustomView>` and then inflate it in my recycler view.  I prefer this option because I can preview my custom view before deploying it on the device/emulator.

Comment: I should clarify my earlier comment: directly inflating XML _inside the `RecyclerView.Adapter`_ is not using a custom view—certainly not in the case of the question that was asked, where a factory method provides a fully configured view already.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the pattern of different `ViewTypes` in a `RecyclerView.Adapter` as well.

Step 1: Create your custom view in the `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = PanelViewFactory.createPanel(..);
    return new PanelViewHolder(view);
}
```

Here I'm assuming you'll have to create some kind of a `ViewHolder` for your custom `PanelView`. If you don't need a `ViewHolder` it most likely means you're not doing stuff in the most effective way in your current implementation, so it's a good opportunity to improve :)

Step 2: Bind data in your `PanelViewHolder` in the method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     PanelViewHolder viewHolder = (PanelViewHolder)holder;
     viewHolder.name.setText(...);
     ....
}
```