# Use custom View in a RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-adapter

I have a basic custom View which looks like this:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    private User user;

    private ImageView profilePicture;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_layout, this);

        profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);

        // ACCESS USER MODEL HERE
        // e.g. user.getUsername()
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'd like to access user data in the View (i.e.: `user.getUsername()`).

I also need to be able to use the custom View in a `RecyclerView` Adapter.

Here is what my Adapter currently looks like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    private List<User> userData;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<User> userData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // HOW TO INFLATE THE CUSTOM VIEW?

        // ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(customView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // ANYTHING HERE?
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userData.size();
    }

}
```

How can I inflate the custom View in the Adapter?
Also, should I put anything in `onBindViewHolder()`?

Note: I **must** use a custom View, as I use this View under different Adapters (i.e.: not just this `RecyclerView` Adapter).

Answer (score 56):

Assuming a `CustomView` class that looks something like this:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {
    private User user;
    private ImageView profilePicture;

    // override all constructors to ensure custom logic runs in all cases
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }
    public CustomView(
            Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr,
            int defStyleRes
    ) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        // put all custom logic in this constructor, which always runs
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_layout, this);
        profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    }

    public void setUser(User newUser) {
        user = newUser;
        // ACCESS USER MODEL HERE
        // e.g. user.getUsername()
    }
}
```

Your `RecyclerView.Adapter` and `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` could look something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    // no Context reference needed—can get it from a ViewGroup parameter
    private List<User> userData;

    public MyAdapter(List<User> userData) {
        // make own copy of the list so it can't be edited externally
        this.userData = new ArrayList<User>(userData);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // no need for a LayoutInflater instance—
        // the custom view inflates itself
        CustomView itemView = new CustomView(parent.getContext());
        // manually set the CustomView's size
        itemView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.getCustomView().setUser(userData.get(position));
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CustomView customView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            customView = (CustomView) v;
        }

        public CustomView getCustomView() {
            return customView;
        }
    }
}
```

- The `CustomView` manages its own setup, which occurs in its own constructor and in this case uses inflation of an XML file.  (Alternatively, it could set up its child views programmatically.)
- Because of this, the `RecyclerView.Adapter` doesn't need to perform any inflation—it just creates a new `CustomView` instance, and lets the `CustomView` worry about its own setup.
- The `CustomView` can't get a `User` instance until its `setUser` method is called, so user access cannot occur in the constructor.  In any case, over one `CustomView` lifetime, a `RecyclerView` could ask it to show information for many different users at different times.  The `CustomView` needs to be able to do this.  Therefore, a `setUser` method is introduced.
- Because the `CustomView` is instantiated by code instead of by XML, attributes for size can't be defined in XML.  Therefore, sizing is done programmatically after instantation.
- `onBindViewHolder` simply calls `setUser` on the `CustomView` to link the `CustomView` with the correct `User` instance.
- The `ViewHolder` class is now just a link between a `RecyclerView` item and a `CustomView`.

Using pre-built custom views from another class within `RecyclerView`s (i.e. not inflating XML within the `RecyclerView.Adapter`) never seems to be discussed.  I think it's an excellent idea even when the custom view is exclusively used within a `RecyclerView`, because it [promotes separation of concerns](https://crosp.net/blog/software-architecture/srp-soc-android-settings-example/) and [adherence to the Single Responsibility Principle](https://android.jlelse.eu/single-responsibility-principle-and-context-60e39a28e5bd).

Comment: This is a great answer - and with the last paragraph it becomes a fantastic answer. I've started using custom views in all my RecyclerView Adapters, and the result is so clean

Comment: Thanks, Luke—I appreciate your compliments.  I'm still amazed that this approach isn't adopted more often in projects I see.

Comment: remember to change the RecyclerView.Adapter adapter parameter to your custom view holder

Comment: @AlexPeters you say "Because the `CustomView` is instantiated by code instead of by XML, attributes for size can't be defined in XML. Therefore, sizing is done programmatically after instantiation."  What about this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690715/4070848 ?

Comment: @drmrbrewer, sorry, but I don't understand.  Could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: @AlexPeters it was more an observation than a question I suppose.  The linked post shows that you can still define your attributes in XML, then read them as an AttributeSet and pass them as the second argument in your custom view constructor.  Maybe handy if you already have lots of custom attributes defined in XML... can migrate to your suggested approach (thanks btw) and yet keep the attributes defined via XML.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  Sounds like a perfectly good approach if your custom component inflates from XML in the first place, and especially if that component relies on specific size constraints at its topmost level.  I don't think I gave too much consideration to what size values are possible/acceptable once wrapped in a `ViewHolder`.  I guess the sizing constraints I put in my answer above were based purely off what I figured might be the most appropriate.  I don't know how well things might function if the child isn't as wide as the parent, for example.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> CustomView extends RelativeLayout {
> ```

You have a View already (well, a `ViewGroup`)

> HOW TO INFLATE THE CUSTOM VIEW?

You don't need to... The point of a Custom View object is to not need XML, therefore no inflation.

You can create `new CustomView()`, but you need to set all the layout parameters, which looks cleaner in XML, I think.

---

Most `RecyclerView` tutorials show [inflating via XML](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView#creating-the-custom-row-layout) though.

> ```
> View customView = inflater.inflate(...);
> ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(customView);
> ```

That should work because in the class chain, you have `CustomView > RelativeLayout > ViewGroup > View`

> ```
> LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
> ```

Like I said before, you don't need this if there is no XML file you want to inflate.

You also don't need the `context` variable.

`parent.getContext()` is a fine solution.

> ```
> // ANYTHING HERE?
> ```

Well, yeah, you should "bind" the `ViewHolder` with the data that the `ViewHolder` should hold.

Again, most, if not all, tutorials cover this.

Comment: You mention that most/all tutorials cover using an external view class as the view for a `ViewHolder`.  Could you please link one or two?  I feel I've looked at a lot of tutorials on the topic of `RecyclerView`s and `ViewHolder`s and I don't think I've seen this particular thing mentioned ever.

Comment: @Alex https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView#creating-the-custom-row-layout &  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: Okay.  The question states that the custom view needs to be used both within and outside a `RecyclerView` though, so inflating XML directly isn't really an option.  Nonetheless, your answer hits the nail on the head as far as instantiating the custom view, passing a `Context` instance, and needing to manually set layout parameters go.

Answer (score -2):

**list_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_160sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/close"
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter.java

```
public class yourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder> {


private Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> mylist;

public yourAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> checklist) {
    mContext = context;
    mylist = checklist;
}

@Override
public yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
    return new yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.name.setText(adap.getName());


}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mylist.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    Imageview content;


    public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        close= (Imageview) itemView.findViewById(R.id.close);

    }
}
```

}

Then call the adapter class in activity where you want

https://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/

Comment: "Note: I must use a custom view, as I use this view under different adapters (i.e. not just this RecyclerView adapter)."