# Using a custom view as the item in RecyclerView - constraint layout can't handle children with match constraint width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RecyclerView`, in which the item views are created by inflating a layout **within a custom view**, with a `ConstraintLayout` at its root.

When I set the child view to have width `wrap_content` it works fine.

But when I set the second child view to have width `0dp` ("match_constraint"), strange things happen.

Here's my item layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="TextView"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark_primary"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTextView"
    tools:text="TextView"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When myTextView2 has width `wrap_content`, all is good. But when I make it `0dp`, all hell breaks loose.

The issue only occurs on the second TextView - the first TextView can have width `wrap_content` or `0dp`, and both work as expected. But when the second TextView has width `0dp`, different issues arise:

myTextView: wrap_content, myTextView1: wrap_content - no issue

myTextView: 0dp, myTextView1: wrap_content - no issue

myTextView: 0dp, myTextView1: 0dp - no items show, infinite scroll

myTextView: wrap_content, myTextView1: 0dp - myTextView shows as a small column on the left of the screen, the rest of the width is blank

Are there any fixes?

Comment: try setting left and right constraints as well.

Comment: add this as well: app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" - @KaranMer the left right constraints are not needed whe you define start/end instead

Comment: also try adding `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` to your textview after setting width to 0dp

Comment: Adding `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` makes the TextView wrap, exactly as it does with width set to `wrap_content`. But I need width to fill the parent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue arose because I was using a custom view, instead of inflating a layout. The solution is to programmatically specify layout constraints in `onCreateViewHolder`, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123513/6007104

Specifically:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // no need for a LayoutInflater instance—
    // the custom view inflates itself
    CustomView itemView = new CustomView(parent.getContext());
    // manually set the CustomView's size - this is what I was missing
    itemView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote this enough, this was my exact issue too.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It might be issue with you forgot to add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Comment: Sadly this makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

i tested your layout and reproduce your problem:
my solution, hope it works : 
when you inflate your recyclerview item layout in onCreateViewHolder
change `null` to `parent` as second parameter
`override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RvViewHolder {
            val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_temp_recyclerview, parent, false)
            return RvViewHolder(rootView)
        }`

java_version:

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int type) {
            View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_layout, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(itemView);
        }
```

then you can set width of both child views to `0dp`

tip: when you set width to match_constraint or `0dp` you don't need `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias`

Comment: Sadly I can't do this, as I am using a custom view, not inflating a layout