# Why are my custom view RecyclerView items "invisible"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, view, android-custom-view

I need to `onDraw` the items of a `RecyclerView`. Using an approach "discovered" at [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522121/use-custom-view-in-a-recyclerview-adapter), I have gotten - um - partway there.

Note that I ultimately want to `onDraw` "over" the custom view. Meaning call `super` to let the default drawing occur, then `paint` over unused areas of the (view's) `canvas`.

Before starting down this "custom view to allow `onDraw`" road, I had what you see on the **left** below:

[image]    [image]   [image]

Afterward, I had all "invisible" views (**middle** image above). I say "invisible" because they were still there to be clicked. To help me visualize things (and a bit of `onDraw` proof of concept) I overrode `onDraw`  in the custom `PuzzleView` view, simply calling `canvas.drawRect` to cover the entire canvas in Green, and now see the **right** image above.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Also, if it occurs to you that - well, why don't I simply `onDraw` the whole thing - that's not practical for a variety of reasons.

So, here's my `PuzzleAdapter` as it is now:

```
class PuzzleAdapter(private val puzzles: List<Puzzle>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PuzzleAdapter.PuzzleHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PuzzleAdapter.PuzzleHolder {
        //val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_puzzle, parent, false)
        //not inflating, creating PuzzleView (which is inflating itself)
        val v = PuzzleView(parent.context)
        v.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        return PuzzleHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = puzzles.size

    //unchanged between these two versions
    override fun onBindViewHolder(h: PuzzleAdapter.PuzzleHolder, pos: Int) {
        val p = puzzles[pos]
        h.view.puzzleItem_text_ndx.text = "# " + p.descr()
        h.view.puzzleItem_text_details.text = "Ndx: ${p.puzzleNdx}"
        h.view.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("##", "PuzzleHolder.onClick (bunch#${p.parentBunch.bunchID}; puzzle#${p.puzzleNdx})")
            val action = BunchFragmentDirections.navBunchToPuzzle(PuzzleParcel(p.parentBunch.bunchID, p.puzzleNdx))
            it.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    inner class PuzzleHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val view: PuzzleView
        init {
            view = v as PuzzleView
        }
    }
}
```

**PuzzleAdapter before**:

```
class PuzzleAdapter(private val puzzles: List<Puzzle>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PuzzleAdapter.PuzzleHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PuzzleAdapter.PuzzleHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_puzzle, parent, false)
        return PuzzleHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = puzzles.size

    //unchanged between these two versions
    override fun onBindViewHolder(h: PuzzleAdapter.PuzzleHolder, pos: Int) {
        val p = puzzles[pos]
        h.view.puzzleItem_text_ndx.text = "# " + p.descr()
        h.view.puzzleItem_text_details.text = "Ndx: ${p.puzzleNdx}"
        h.view.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("##", "PuzzleHolder.onClick (bunch#${p.parentBunch.bunchID}; puzzle#${p.puzzleNdx})")
            val action = BunchFragmentDirections.navBunchToPuzzle(PuzzleParcel(p.parentBunch.bunchID, p.puzzleNdx))
            it.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    inner class PuzzleHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        var view: View = v
    }
}
```

**PuzzleView** (the **custom view** I am using with the Adapter):

```
class PuzzleView : RelativeLayout {
    constructor (context: Context) : super(context) { init(context, null, 0) }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) { init(context, attrs, 0) }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) { init(context, attrs, defStyle) }

    private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_puzzle, this)
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        //this.layout(l, t, r, b)
    }

    val rect = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
    val paint = Paint()
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas)
        Log.d("##", "PuzzleView.onDraw()")
        rect.right = width - 10
        rect.bottom = height - 10
        val bkgrColor = ContextCompat.getColor(App.context, R.color.Green)
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.color = bkgrColor
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)
    }
}
```

A few thoughts on the above class/code:

- `override fun onLayout` is required
- I have other custom views that work fine (not in relation to a RecyclerView) with an empty `onLayout`
- I tried (it's commented out in the above code) `this.layout(l, t, r, b)` but get a stack overflow exception

My only real thoughts here are (1) that there's something I'm supposed to be doing in this `onLayout` method, but I can't think of what; or (2) there's something wrong with the way that I'm inflating `item_puzzle`, but - again - I can't think of what. (I tried a few things on this, to no avail). I cannot think of anything else!

And here's all the other code I think could possibly be relevant:

From the **Fragment containing the RecyclerView** (it's what is shown in the above three images):

```
    bunch_recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this.context, 3)
    bunch_recycler.adapter = PuzzleAdapter(bunch.puzzles)
```

Finally, the **XML for** the item itself, **item_puzzle**:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/facadeLight"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_puzzle"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/puzzleItem_text_ndx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/showg"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="17"
            android:textColor="@color/facadeDark"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/puzzleItem_text_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/puzzleItem_text_ndx"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="details"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Also, if "custom view to allow onDraw" isn't the correct (or best) way of accomplishing my goal here, please let me know that as well.

Using:

- Windows 10
- Android Studio 3.4
- Kotlin 1.3.31
- Gradle 3.4.0
- and the following:

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
```

### Afterthought

I saw (in a 4 1/2-year-old [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiU06u_vuG8&t=67s) overriding `getView` to assign subviews in a similar-seeming situation. There is no `getView` method to override in today's `RecyclerView`. The closest thing I see is `getItemViewType(position: Int): Int` which doesn't seem promising either (I read up on it a bit). Just thought I'd mention this in case it triggers a thought for you (where it didn't for me).